# How to parse a JSON list into an object

Tags: c#, json, list, parsing

I want to parse this code into an object in C#. I was trying to find an answer but every post included data with key values which this doesn't have. Every piece of data is separated by semicolons.

```
[
  [
    1499040000000,
    "0.01634790",
    "0.80000000",
    "0.01575800",
    "0.01577100",
    "148976.11427815",
    1499644799999,
    "2434.19055334",
    308,
    "1756.87402397",
    "28.46694368",
    "17928899.62484339"
  ]
]
```

Comment: 1) According to [Curious concept](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) it is valid Json. What is the result when you call [Newtonsoft's](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(jsonstring)`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with Product.

Comment: You might be able to deserialize this to a `List<T>` for some appropriate `T`, where the members of `T` correspond to the array entries and you are using `ObjectToArrayConverter<T>` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39462464/3744182).  Or you could just load using `JArray.Parse(jsonString)` from [tag:json.net].

Comment: [See here](https://app.quicktype.io?share=9Pw1xdo0RVruD9g4XjW6) for an auto-generated class to parse your JSON.

Comment: You mention semicolons (`;`), did you mean commas (`,`)? Just so that we know that you don't have a different file construct than the one you posted. In any case, what you have is a collection (`[...]`) or collections (`[...]`) of objects (`149904000000` and `"0.01634790"`), since the objects doesn't have any common type, strings, integers, floating point numbers, you're probably best off by deserializing this as `List<List<object>>` or `object[][]`, so `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[][]>(json)` should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: Parsing a non-JSON array-only api response to a class object with x properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48429702).

Answer (score 2):

To quick and easy get the object that Visual Studio think of the Json, you can copy the complete Json and then go to `Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes`. For me, that generates the following for the complete Json that you posted:

```
    public class JsonClass
    {
        public object[][] Property1 { get; set; }
    }
```

*(This could potentionally be `object[]` depending on incoming Json.)*

This should be possible to `JsonConvert` into a `List<JsonClass>` and after that, depending on your scenario, try to parse the data to correct data type if that is needed.

I think that another way of doing it is also as [@dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc) mentioned in the comment:

> You might be able to deserialize this to a `List<T>` for some appropriate `T`, where the members of `T` correspond to the array entries and you are using `ObjectToArrayConverter<T>` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461518/c-sharp-json-net-deserialize-response-that-uses-an-unusual-data-structure/39462464#39462464). Or you could just load using `JArray.Parse(jsonString)` from [json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json.net).

Comment: I am using the class you provided with this code `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<JsonClass>>(json);` Getting the error _Unhandled Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'tradingbot.Domain.JsonClass' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly._

Comment: @user3434894 - The outer `JsonClass` object isn't necessary, just do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object [][]>(jsonString);`