# How to deserialize array into wrapper object?

Tags: c#, json.net

I want Json.NET deserializer to be able to directly use: `ArrayWrapper[] Array { get; set; }` property.

Should I write custom `JsonConverter` or there is easier way?

```
public class Obj {

    //public ArrayWrapper[] Array { get; set; } // I want it to work!!!

    [JsonProperty( "array" )]
    public int[][] Array_ { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public ArrayWrapper[] Array => Array_.Select( i => new ArrayWrapper( i ) ).ToArray();

}

public struct ArrayWrapper {

    private readonly int[] array;

    public int Item0 => array[ 0 ];
    public int Item1 => array[ 1 ];

    public ArrayWrapper(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public static implicit operator ArrayWrapper(int[] array) {
        return new ArrayWrapper( array );
    }
}
```

Note: the array of arrays is returned by this API: https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#klinecandlestick-data.  I want to convert inner array into object.

Comment: Or for example I want to wrap root array into object with array property.

Comment: 1) What JSON are you trying to serialize or deserialize?  Can you please [edit] your question to show your desired JSON?  2) `ArrayWrapper` has no public getter for `array`, only for the first two entries (which are assumed to exist).  What should happen when the array is the wrong length?

Comment: OK, still not sure I understand your question, but if I do the easiest way to do this is 1) make `ArrayWrapper` implement `IEnumerable<int>`, and 2) add a `public ArrayWrapper(IEnumerable<int> enumerable)` constructor.  Once done, Json.NET will treat `ArrayWrapper` as a read-only collection and (de) serialize it as such.  Demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jHHx86.  Is that what you want?

Comment: This API returns array of arrays: https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#klinecandlestick-data I want to convert inner array into object. Thank you for your answer. I guess I'll have to use it. But this is not the perfect solution (:

Comment: *But this is not the perfect solution (:* - then should I add an answer?  Or can you [edit] your question to explain your requirements more clearly?  There are already answers about deserializing Binance Kline/Candlestick data, see [C#: Parsing a non-JSON array-only api response to a class object with x properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48431099),

Comment: Yes, add your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to capture a collection inside a surrogate wrapper object, the easiest way to do so is to make the wrapper appear to be a *read-only collection* to Json.NET.  To do that, you must:

- Implement `IEnumerable<T>` for some `T` (here `int`).
- Add a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` for the same `T`.  (From experimentation, a constructor that takes `T []` is not sufficient.)

Thus if you define your `ArrayWrapper` as follows:

```
public struct ArrayWrapper : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private readonly int[] array;

    public int Item0 { get { return array[ 0 ]; } }
    public int Item1 { get { return array[ 1 ]; } }

    public ArrayWrapper(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public ArrayWrapper(IEnumerable<int> enumerable) 
    {
        this.array = enumerable.ToArray();
    }

    public static implicit operator ArrayWrapper(int[] array) {
        return new ArrayWrapper( array );
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (array ?? Enumerable.Empty<int>()).GetEnumerator();
    }

    #region IEnumerable Members

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You will be able to serialize and deserialize `Obj` into the following JSON:

```
{"Array":[[1,101]]}
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jHHx86).

However, in comments you mention your array actually has a fixed schema as documented in *[Public Rest API for Binance: Kline/Candlestick data](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#klinecandlestick-data)*.  If so, you could adopt the approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48431099/3744182) to *[C#: Parsing a non-JSON array-only api response to a class object with x properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48429702/3744182)* which specifically addresses Binance Kline/Candlestick data:

- Define an explicit data model for your data.
- Label each property with `[JsonProperty(Order = N)]` to indicate relative array positions.  (`[DataContract]` and `[DataMember(Order = N)]` could be used instead.)
- Use the converter `ObjectToArrayConverter<ArrayWrapper>()` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39462464/3744182) to *[C# JSON.NET - Deserialize response that uses an unusual data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39461518/3744182)*.

I.e. for the specific model shown in your question, modify its definition as follows:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectToArrayConverter<ArrayWrapper>))]
public struct ArrayWrapper
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
    public int Item0 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
    public int Item1 { get; set; }
}
```

And you will be able to (de)serialize the same JSON.  Note that the converter is entirely generic and can be reused any time the pattern of (de)serializing an array with a fixed schema into an object arises.

(You might also want to change the `struct` to a `class` since mutable structs are [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/441309/3744182).)

Demo fiddles #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MIOF84) and #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/clNlC9) showing the use of a `JsonConverter` attribute applied to one of the serializable properties.

Comment: I chose the second option and got the problem. My property has `JsonConverter` but `ArrayToObjectConverter` doesn't use it and throw exception. The problem in line `jToken.ToObject( prop.PropertyType, serializer )`. jToken is long but PropertyType is DateTime.

Comment: I guess I should convert JArray into JObject.

Comment: @wishmaster35 - answer updated, however in the future you really should ask another question **with a new [mcve] that demonstrates your problem** since the initial answer met the needs of your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I made my version of `ArrayToObjectConverter`.

My `ArrayToObjectConverter` just convert `JArray` into `JObject` with properties: Item1, Item2, Item3... and deserialize this object.

```
public class ArrayToObjectConverter : JsonConverter {

    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanWrite => true;


    public override bool CanConvert(Type type) {
        return false;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type type, object existingInstance, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        var contract = (JsonObjectContract) serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract( type );
        var instance = existingInstance ?? contract.DefaultCreator();

        var array = JArray.Load( reader );
        var obj = Convert( array );
        serializer.Populate( obj.CreateReader(), instance );
        return instance;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object instance, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        var contract = (JsonObjectContract) serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract( instance.GetType() );
        var properties = contract.Properties.Where( IsSerializable );

        var values = properties.Select( i => i.ValueProvider.GetValue( instance ) );
        serializer.Serialize( writer, values );
    }


    // Helpers
    private static JObject Convert(JArray array) {
        var obj = new JObject();
        for (var i = 0; i < array.Count; i++) {
            obj.Add( "Item" + i, array[ i ] );
        }
        return obj;
    }

    private static bool IsSerializable(JsonProperty property) {
        return !property.Ignored && property.Readable && property.Writable;
    }


}
```

You should use `ArrayToObjectConverter` with objects like this:

```
[JsonConverter( typeof( ArrayToObjectConverter ) )]
public class Obj {

    [JsonProperty]
    internal string Item0 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    internal decimal Item1 { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Text { get => Item0; set => Item0 = value; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public decimal Number { get => Item1; set => Item1 = value; }

}
```

Only I'm not sure if `JsonObjectContract.Properties` will always have right order or not.

Comment: `WriteJson` is not using property `JsonConverter` (: